# string to (possible) integer. Error Handling: Filter with regex or try...catch?

Tags: python, c++, regex, error-handling, try-catch

Sitting before this problem and I'm not sure which path I should choose.

I get string inputs representing an ID.
Most of the time it will be meaningfull keynames to look up the actual ID in a table/dict.
But direct integer ID input should be possible as well. But these will come as a string.

---

I'm not sure if this is more a style question or if there is a huge leaning towards one option.

Option 1:
Use a regexp, check for integer,
if true convert.

Option 2:

```
try 
    ID = string.tointeger()
catch
    ID = table[string]
```

I'm leaning towards the try...catch option as it looks cleaner. But I'm not sure if avoiding error handling via regex would deep down actually be the cleaner way and *should be* preferred.

Having no deeper knowledge about about try...catch; if it is actually pretty smooth *'use it if you like'* or a hiccup *'avoid if you can'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"He who would sacrifice correctness for performance deserves neither[!?]."*

TL;DR:

`try...catch` can be very fast. Looking cleaner than code trying to ship around errors. On the other hand it might be harder to follow for others when there are big code blocks and there happens stuff behind the scene which you possible don't want to have.
This is of course language dependent

regexp can be very slow and a cheap filter before it can save you.

--

So trying to answer this myself now:

I hoped for a general answer but in the end of course it is language dependent.
While doing research I often found the arguments *it is expensive, creating the exception object, collecting the call stack...* Sure makes sense. But often there was no explanation and it felt more like a Stigma or Superstition: try...catch is bad.

---

From my tests (C++): The try...catch method was the fastest overall. A mere 3% drop in execution speed. Two simple "Does the string start with digits?" `"^-?\d+"` regexp for integer and float were a 50% drop and as I do some substring analysis after these 50%^x became noticeable.

---

In the end stumpled over Bjarne Stroustrup's (creator or C++) own FAQ:
http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#exceptions-why

> What good can using exceptions do for me? The basic answer is: Using
>   exceptions for error handling makes you code simpler, cleaner, and
>   less likely to miss errors. But what's wrong with "good old errno and
>   if-statements"? The basic answer is: Using those, your error handling
>   and your normal code are closely intertwined. That way, your code gets
>   messy and it becomes hard to ensure that you have dealt with all
>   errors (think "spaghetti code" or a "rat's nest of tests").
>   [...]
>
> Common objections to the use of exceptions: 
>   but exceptions are expensive!: Not really. Modern C++ implementations
>   reduce the overhead of using exceptions to a few percent (say, 3%) and
>   that's compared to no error handling. Writing code with error-return
>   codes and tests is not free either. As a rule of thumb, exception
>   handling is extremely cheap when you don't throw an exception. It
>   costs nothing on some implementations. All the cost is incurred when
>   you throw an exception: that is, "normal code" is faster than code
>   using error-return codes and tests. You incur cost only when you have
>   an error.

Well now in the end I decided to use simple manual filter 1st Char in array[-,0-9] before the regexp. Which might be 10% slower than try...catch but does not throw errors 80% of the time. Still good performance and nice code :)

---

From the Python glossary: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp

> **EAFP**
>   *Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.* This common Python
>   coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and
>   catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast
>   style is characterized by the presence of many `try` and `except`
>   statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many
>   other languages such as C.
>
> **LBYL**
>   *Look before you leap.* This coding style explicitly tests for pre-conditions before making calls or lookups. This style contrasts
>   with the EAFP approach and is characterized by the presence of many if
>   statements.
>   In a multi-threaded environment, the LBYL approach can risk introducing a race condition between “the looking” and “the leaping”.
>   For example, the code, if key in mapping: return mapping[key] can fail
>   if another thread removes key from mapping after the test, but before
>   the lookup. This issue can be solved with locks or by using the EAFP
>   approach.